# How to generate a second biblatex bibliography without duplicating entries in the second one?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sectioning, multiple-citations

I am trying to add a 'Methods' section to my report, and am struggling with generating the references as I would like, so would appreciate a little help. So far, a MWE of the output looks like this:

[image]

Any source that has been referred to in the Main Section correctly appears in the Main References. However, I will often cite a source in the Methods section which has already been referenced once in the Main Section, but it appears in the Methods References as well. I would like to have only unique ones to appear in the Methods Refs, and not have duplicates in both sections.

In the example above, the Horowitz and Hill reference should NOT appear again in the Methods Refs. But I should still be able to reference it in Methods and it should point to (1). How can I achieve this?

The code to generate the above example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric-comp,
            firstinits=true,
            sorting=none,
            doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\addbibresource{bibliography_list.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}
Here is my reference for the main section: \autocite{horowitz1989art}.
\printbibliography[title={Main References}]

\subsection{Methods}
\begin{refsection}
My references for the Methods are: \autocite{bloch2000measurement,horowitz1989art,DfE}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Methods References}]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

and the bib file

```
@book{horowitz1989art,
  title={The art of electronics},
  author={Horowitz, Paul and Hill, Winfield},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Cambridge Univ. Press}
}

@online{DfE,
  author = {},
  organization = {{Department for Education}},
  title = {Guidance for schools: coronavirus (COVID-19)},
  url = {https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/guidance-for-schools-coronavirus-covid-19},
  urldate = {2020-07-24},
  year = 2020
}

@article{bloch2000measurement,
  title={Measurement of the spatial coherence of a trapped Bose gas at the phase transition},
  author={Bloch, Immanuel and H{\"a}nsch, Theodor W and Esslinger, Tilman},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={403},
  number={6766},
  pages={166--170},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`refsection`s are always kept completely independent, so you can't easily print only references that were not cited in the previous section in section 1. Note also that with `refsection`s the same work may get a different number in different `refsections`, so you can't leave out entries in the bibliography anyway as your readers would have no way to identify the sources correctly.

I suggest you use `refsegment`s. `refsegment`s are similar to `refsection`s, but they are not kept separate. Instead they act more of less like an additional keyword or a category classification: `biblatex` can filter bibliographies by `refsegment`s.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in '*only* in this `refsegment`'-test. That has to be built manually. In your MWE that is fairly straightforward, but it may get a bit more complex if you use more `refsgement`s (because you have to stack `not segment=0 and ... and not segment=n-1` to get to the references in `segment=n`; refsegments are started counting from 0, everything that is not behind a `\newrefsegment` or inside a `\begin{refsegment}...\end{refsegment}` belongs to segment 0). We use bibfilters to be able to negate the test for a `refsegment`. But strictly speaking the first test `filter=onlymain,` could be replaced by `segment=0,` in this MWE.

Note that we will need the `defernumbers` option for continuous numbering in the bibliographies (well, strictly speaking the `sorting=none,` means that in this setup `defernumbers` is probably not that essential, but it is with other `sorting` options). This option may need a few more LaTeX runs than you are used to. If you get weird output, delete the `.aux` file and rerun LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric-comp,
            firstinits=true,
            sorting=none,
            defernumbers,
            doi=false, eprint=false, url=false, isbn=false,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\defbibfilter{onlymain}{%
  segment=0
}

\defbibfilter{onlymethods}{%
  not segment=0
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{horowitz1989art,
  title     = {The Art of Electronics},
  author    = {Horowitz, Paul and Hill, Winfield},
  year      = {1989},
  publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
}
@online{DfE,
  author  = {{Department for Education}},
  title   = {Guidance for schools: coronavirus (COVID-19)},
  url     = {https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/guidance-for-schools-coronavirus-covid-19},
  urldate = {2020-07-24},
  year    = 2020,
}
@article{bloch2000measurement,
  title   = {Measurement of the Spatial Coherence
             of a Trapped {Bose} Gas at the Phase Transition},
  author  = {Bloch, Immanuel and Hänsch, Theodor W. and Esslinger, Tilman},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume  = {403},
  number  = {6766},
  pages   = {166--170},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}
Here is my reference for the main section: \autocite{horowitz1989art}.
\printbibliography[filter=onlymain, title={Main References}]

\subsection{Methods}
\begin{refsegment}
My references for the Methods are: \autocite{bloch2000measurement,horowitz1989art,DfE}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,filter=onlymethods,title={Methods References}]
\end{refsegment}

\end{document}
```

[image: First bibliography with entry 1, second with 2 and 3.]

---

In a long document with several segments (or even with just two longer segments) the list might be a bit hard to navigate because your reader may not know a priori in which reference list to look for a reference (they'd have to keep in mind the last number for each reference list). It may help your readers along if you add

```
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=M]
```

before the `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,filter=onlymethods,title={Methods References}]` in the *Methods* section. That way your readers get a simple visual cue as to whether to look.

---

In general I find that as a reader I prefer a single global bibliography over several smaller ones for the simple reason that after a while I have figure out where the global bibliography is, so I can easily switch back and forth. If there are several bibliographies, there are more places I would need to skip to. This is especially painful if it is not glaringly obvious from the references themselves (or the surroundings, say the chapter number) where I have to look for the reference.  (Of course some of that can be mitigated to some degree with hyperlinks, but they won't work in print and sometimes I don't even want to jump in a PDF, so I have the document open twice: I'll be reading one version and I'll have the other version open in the reference section, if I have to skip around several times, that makes my workflow harder.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest `refsection` environments, but you can make subsets of references using keywords, said "AAA" and "BBB", e.g.:

```
@book{horowitz1989art,
  title={The art of electronics},
  author={Horowitz, Paul and Hill, Winfield},
  keywords={AAA, whatever},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Cambridge Univ. Press}
}
```

Then, you only need print by keyword without sorting cites:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bibliography_list.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}

Here is my reference for the main section: \autocite{horowitz1989art}.

\printbibliography[title={Main References},keyword=AAA]

\subsection{Methods}

My references for the Methods are: \autocite{horowitz1989art,bloch2000measurement,DfE}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Methods References},keyword=BBB]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: mwe]