# Separate references for appendix, without duplicates with main body (automatically handled)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I would like to **automatically** put in one section all the references that are coming from the main text, and in another section all the references that are coming from the Appendix **and which are not already cited in main text**.

I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98660/two-bibliographies-one-for-main-text-and-one-for-appendix), but it does not solve my issue since:

- either duplicated references are not removed from the appendix
- either I have to manually tag each reference (by using a different cite command or a different `.bib` file), and I don't want to do that myself as it's super hard to always keep track of where citations appear in a constantly moving text with potentially multiple co-authors.

I'm fine with either bibtex or biblatex solutions.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myrefs.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
    {\LaTeX} is aTuring-complete
    (procedural) markup language and
    typesetting processor~\parencite{Lamport:94}.


\printbibliography
\appendix
\section{Second}
\begin{refsection}
   The ultimate reference of {\TeX} is~\parencite{Knuth:1990} and \parencite{Lamport:94}, which should NOT be cited in this section.
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for `biblatex`, which combines `filters` and `refsegment`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myrefs.bib}
\defbibfilter{appendixOnlyFilter}{
  segment=1 % Segment 1 will be chosen to be the one in appendix
  and not segment=0 % Default segment is 0
}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Body}
{\LaTeX} is aTuring-complete (procedural) markup language and typesetting processor~\cite{Lamport:94}.

\printbibliography[segment=0]
\appendix
\newrefsegment %% <== increases the segment number (0 by default)

\section{Appendix}
The ultimate reference of {\TeX} is~\cite{Knuth:1990} and \cite{Lamport:94}, which should NOT be cited in this section.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,filter=appendixOnlyFilter]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I would have recommended. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555312/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245971/35864.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this template and create your own file within 3 minutes, which is very simple to use and will save you time and effort.**

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/multiple-bibliographies-with-bibunits/ktgbztpwjnpb

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Multiple bibliographies with bibunits}

\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
\section{A section}
This is the first part with citations from \texttt{refs1.bib}, using the \texttt{plain} style. \cite{lees2010theoretical}

\putbib[refs1]
\end{bibunit}


\begin{bibunit}[alpha]
\section{Another section}
This is the first part with citations from \texttt{refs2.bib}, using the \texttt{alpha} style. \cite{belkin2002using,berard1994embedding}

\putbib[refs2]
\end{bibunit}


\end{document}
```

**refs1.bib**

```
@article{lees2010theoretical,
  title={Theoretical maximum capacity as benchmark for empty vehicle redistribution in personal rapid transit},
  author={Lees-Miller, John and Hammersley, John and Wilson, R},
  journal={Transportation Research Record: Journal of the Transportation Research Board},
  number={2146},
  pages={76--83},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Transportation Research Board of the National Academies}
}
```

**refs2.bib**

```
@inproceedings{belkin2002using,
  title={Using manifold stucture for partially labeled classification},
  author={Belkin, Mikhail and Niyogi, Partha},
  booktitle={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  pages={929--936},
  year={2002}
}

@article{berard1994embedding,
  title={Embedding Riemannian manifolds by their heat kernel},
  author={B{\'e}rard, Pierre and Besson, G{\'e}rard and Gallot, Sylvain},
  journal={Geometric \& Functional Analysis GAFA},
  volume={4},
  number={4},
  pages={373--398},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

ps: I searched Google for 2 hours. I even tried Overleaf's official solution: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document. It did not work. Then I found this link created by an Overleaf user.